# wget and encoding. how to force utf-8?

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, wget, iso-8859-1, cyrillic

When I try to download the link (ubuntu 16.04, wget 1.17.1):

```
wget --remote-encoding=UTF-8 http://www.altai_terr.vybory.izbirkom.ru/region/altai_terr?action=ik&vrn=4224065120534
```

I get a file:

```
>cat altai_terr\?action\=ik 

    ...
    <div class="center-colm">
    <h2>????????????? ???????? ?????????? ????</h2>
    <p>
    <strong>????? ????????: </strong><span id="address_ik"><span>656035, ????? ???????, ???????? ?.?.??????, 59</span></span>
    </p>
    ...
```

I check the file:

```
>file -bi altai_terr\?action\=ik 
text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

I check installed locales:

```
…
en_US
en_US.iso88591
en_US.iso885915
en_US.utf8
…
ru_RU
ru_RU.cp1251
ru_RU.iso88595
ru_RU.koi8r
ru_RU.utf8
russian
ru_UA
ru_UA.koi8u
ru_UA.utf8
…
```

How can I download the file without "???"?

P.S. 
If I do run python 2.7 and this code:

```
x = 'http://www.altai_terr.vybory.izbirkom.ru/region/altai_terr?action=ik&vrn=4224065120534'
page_uik = requests.get(url = x)
print page_uik.text
```

I do get:

```
...
<div class="center-colm">
<h2>Участковая избирательная комиссия №1767</h2>
<p>
<strong>Адрес комиссии: </strong><span id="address_ik"><span>659595, Алтайский край, Усть-Пристанский район, село Коробейниково, улица Комсомольская, дом 33а</span>, дом культуры</span>
</p>
...
```

Answer (score 4):

I have to convert the file after downloading with this command:

```
iconv -f CP1251 -t UTF-8 altai_terr\?action\=ik
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a `wget` business.

You can ask webserver about a specific encoding, but probably the webserver will ignore you.

Webserver will tell you what he think it is the encoding, but never trust the server.

HTML also allow author to specify the encoding (so without need to ask to the system administrator/web master).

So it is your task, after you get the document, to check what it is the encoding, and then to translate it, and to handle errors and exceptions. You may see UTF-8 site with invalid codes, or also often, site with several encoding (usually because of dynamic generation of different part, with wrong assumption of encoding).

So get what `wget` give you, and you need to do yourself the decoding.

Comment: I believe I understand what you mean. I got I file with the encoding I have no I idea. And I have to convert it. I have tried few option and finally got this: `code` iconv -f CP1251 -t UTF-8 altai_terr\?action\=ik `code`

Comment: yeah. The difficult part is to get the CP1251 in a reliable manner. HTML should tell you what encoding (I think you noticed that HTTP gave you the wrong encoding). Python do also the decoding (Python slogan: "batteries included"). But I recommend python3, which corrected a lot of problems/errors with encodings.